# Are there problems with using SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Groups with Windows 2008R2?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-clustering

[Cross posted to [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/35012/8411)]

Brent Ozar published this webcast ([slides](http://www.mssqltips.com/webcasts/Real-LifeSQLServer2012_AlwaysOnLessonsLearned_20130131.pdf), [video](http://www.mssqltips.com/webcast2.asp?id=186) with free registration) entitled "Real-Life SQL Server 2012: AlwaysOn Lessons Learned", in which he repeatedly states, with varying degrees of force, that

> using Windows 2008R2 with SQL Server 2012 Availability Groups is a bad idea

Among issues he raises are:

1. Quorum recalculation (a feature of Windows Failover Clustering introduced in Windows 2012)
2. Numerous bugs requiring Windows Hotfixes ([list in AlwaysOn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878487.aspx#WinHotfixes), ["StackOverflow patch"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2777201)), though I'm much less interested in problems that are fixed by bringing my deployment up to date.

He doesn't talk about other specifics of why using AGs with Win2008R2 is a bad idea, other than stating that AlwaysOn "pushes Windows clustering harder than any other app, and is uncovering breaking points". It is worth noting though that this is a supported configuration ([AlwaysOn system requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878487.aspx#SystemReqsForAOAG)).

**What problems have been seen in new deployments using SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn Availability Groups with Windows Server 2008 R2**, and are these eliminated by using Windows 2012? Are there problems seen in Windows 2008R2 that are fixed in Windows 2012 but do not have hotfixes available in 2008R2?

Comment: Interesting question! Might be better suited for the [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site though.

Comment: Yes that's a good suggestion. It's now here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/35012/8411

Answer (score 0):

I have worked setting up always in both windows 2008 and 2012. I didnt face much difference between them